# A person paid me with a fake check. How can I report a fraud?

Tags: fraud

A person paid me with a fake check. I deposited the check through an ATM, and the money went into my account, so I made a Bitcoin transfer to him. But yesterday, the bank took the money back from my account because they are fake checks.

I have only the wallet ID and the TX ID. All the other information that they provided to me is fake.

Can I do something?

Answer (score 8):

You cannot do anything aside from trying to seek legal action. Transactions on the bitcoin network cannot be undone.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @m1xolydian answer, You should be careful while selling Bitcoin, Never deal with Bank transaction/Checks/Credit Card Payments as final even if you got the money from the bank to your hands.

Don't you wonder why %99 of Bitcoin wallets don't support credit card payments for buying bitcoins? Because of Bitcoin transactions are final and they can't do a chargeback.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the country, you can often report handling in fake cheques and fake ID's to the relevant authorities e.g Police, Gov't Department, etc. sometimes there are several relevant bureau's.

It is sound business advice to always wait for a cheque to clear before accepting it as payment, which it seems that you did in this case (in Australia once the cheque clears it is ordinarily final - they pass the cheque to the originating bank for verification before honouring it and if you want it done straight away there is a hefty fee but they still run it over to the appropriate branch bank to be checked and cleared) but, nonetheless you need to allow for both clearing time and bounce time after that.