# I saw an ad on Craigslist for a bitcoin runner

Tags: fraud

Hi there I saw an ad for a bitcoin runner.  The person is saying to buy bitcoin with the funds he sent me. I just received an obviously official cashiers check in the mail for $2,900.  Now he wants me to deposit it so that I can access my pay plus use the rest to buy bitcoin.  I have not deposited it yet.  Anyone heard of this? Is this a scam?

Comment: This looks like a fake check scam.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A person paid me with a fake check. How can I report a fraud?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/72142/how-can-i-report-a-fraud)

Comment: This is 99.9999% likely to be a scam.